# Ubuntu Doble pantalla en una con radeon vega 8!

Tags: linux, ubuntu, screen

recientemente cambie mi laptop por una hp pavilion 15 cw-0009la con un amd ryzen 5 y amd radeon vega 8.
El problema es que al iniciar ubuntu live se parte la pantalla en dos y en ambas muestra lo mismo pero en una misma pantalla, si entro a la configuracion marca que detecta dos pantallas, a demas de que de la mitad para abajo solo se estira la ultima linea visible como se muestra en la imagen de abajo 
Alguna idea de como solucionarlo ??
ya probre ubuntu live 15, 16, 18 
[image: al mover el cursor en la primer pantalla se mueve a la par en la otra]

Comment: Quiza te puedan ayudar en otros sitios de stack, como SuperUser https://superuser.com/questions o en stack de Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions . Espero encuentres ayuda

Comment: gracias :) ya publique ahí